# Getting around Series[Sinc] bug

Tags: bugs, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.4**

---

For some reason, `Series` expansion of `Sinc` around `x=0` for low orders fails to generate a `SeriesData`.

```
Series[Sinc[x],{x,0,0}]
Series[Sinc[x],{x,0,1}]
```

> `(*1*)`

This has lead to unfortunate incorrect results in my code.  How do I force `Series` to *always* generate a `SeriesData`?

Comment: Probably a bug. `Sinc[x] + O[x]` doesn't work either. `Series[Sin[x]/x, {x, 0, 0}]` works, though.

Comment: Or use [FunctionExpand](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html)  `Series[Sinc[x] // FunctionExpand, {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: I don't have this problem in versions 10.4.0 and 10.4.1